# Java HttpURLConnection no cookies at login

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to do a login with HttpURLConnection and then get the session cookies...

I already tried that on some test pages on my own server, and that works perfectly. When i send `a=3&b=5` i get `8` as cookie (PHP page adds both together)!
But when i try that at the other page, the output is just the page as if I just sent nothing with POST :(

General suggestions for improvement are welcome! :)

My Code:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("useragent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0");
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
out.writeBytes("USER=tennox&PASS=*****");
out.close();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String line;
String response = new String();
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response = response + line + "\n";
}
in.close();

System.out.println("headers:");
int i = 0;
String header;
while ((header = conn.getHeaderField(i)) != null) {
    String key = conn.getHeaderFieldKey(i);
    System.out.println(((key == null) ? "" : key + ": ") + header);
    i++;
}
String cookies = conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
System.out.println("\nCookies: \"" + cookies + "\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

The cookie path should initially be set with `; Path=/`, also needing a Set-Cookie in the request header of the POST.

Better rewrite it all with an [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/).

Comment: Where/how should i set that?

And the set-cookie like this?
_conn.setRequestProperty("Set-Cookie", "true");_

Comment: `conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie","xxx=yyy; Path=/");` see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Comment: Okay, but where do i know xxx and yyy from?

Comment: In the browser (say Firefox) you can inspect the cookies from the site, and see what to mimick and expect.

Comment: Well, look at this page:
[link](https://sicherheitsserver.net-build.de/gymbel/schuelerportal/ssl/login.html)
There are no cookies before i login, so i send the USER and PASS post data, but i dont get cookies and in the inputstream i get the normal login page...

Comment: Logging in with false data gives a cookie with name PHPSESSID_netsh10319, value c4637af... for domain sicherheitsserver.net-build.de, path /. I would really give HttpClient a try. I picked a [german https example](http://www.java-forum.org/netzwerkprogrammierung/42886-https-apache-httpclient.html).